# Impute missing values by Replicating Previous Value

Tags: sas

My data is in this format:

```
Var1  Var1  Var1 Value1 Imputer_Value1  Value2  Imputer_Value2
    A   A1  A11 6   6   15  15
    A   A1  A11 9   9   14  14
    A   A1  A12 1   1   19  19
    A   A2  A12     1   16  16
    A   A2  A13 10  10  13  13
    A   A2  A13 4   4   .   13
    B   B1  B11 8   8   13  13
    B   B1  B11 9   9   17  17
    B   B1  B12 5   5   18  18
    B   B2  B12 .   5   12  12
    B   B2  B13 2   2   20  20
    B   B2  B13 1   1   .   20
```

I want to impute the missing values by replicating the previous value from the same above group. Can anyone please tell me how to do it? I tried to follow this option. But this does not have multiple value computation option.

```
data imputedData;
 set mydata;
 n=_n_;
 if missing(Value1) then
  do;
   do until (not missing(value1));
     n=n-1;
     set mydata(keep=Value1) point=n;  *second SET statement;
   end;
 end;
run;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there are a few simple ways you can do this. The easiest being use of the `lag` and `coalesce` functions. Unfortunately the `lag` function can sometimes yield unexpected results when missing values are involved.

Here is an example using `lag`.

```
data want;
set have;
* The coalesce function returns the first non-missing value
* and the lag function returns the last value;
value1 = coalesce(value1, lag(value1));
value2 = coalesce(value2, lag(value2));
run;
```

If that does not work then you may have to use a `retain` statement.

```
data want;
set have;
retain val1 val2;
* If it's not the first record do;
if _n_ > 1 then do;
    value1 = coalesce(value1, val1);
    value2 = coalesce(value2, val2);
end;
val1 = value1;
val2 = value2;
run;
```